# Homestead setup does not work

Tags: laravel, homestead

I installed homestead and laravel 5.3
Now I want to setup my homepage and access it locally. Therefore I created this YAML file:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Development/Source/MFServer
      to: /home/vagrant/Development/Source/MFServer

sites:
    - map: loc.medifaktor
      to: /home/vagrant/Development/Source/MFServer/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

and the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   loc.medifaktor
```

But when I access loc.medifaktor I get the error:

> This site can’t be reached loc.medifaktor’s server DNS address could
>   not be found.

Answer (score 1):

The `folders:` attribute is meant as a root folder for all your projects. Change it to:

```
- map: ~/Documents/Development/Source
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Source
```

Make sure your MFServer project is installed in the `Source` folder, so basically like your site mapping now says.

Then reload & provision homestead with `vagrant reload --provision` or `homestead reload --provision` if you've defined an alias.

If you now ssh into homestead, your project's source code should be available in `/Development/Source/[project]`